# Enforcing numeric inputs and sanitizing different formats for IE11 input fields

Tags: javascript, regex, html5, form, fixed-point

I'm working on a web form that functions with numeric inputs. I have `<input type="number">` input fields and with Chrome and Firefox things work nicely since they only allow numeric data to be filled in.

However, I need to support IE11 and it does not enforce the number type when inputting data (but does when submitting data).

Since I want to make it as easy as possible for users (who often copy-paste data from different sources), I wanna sanitize the numbers both on paste as well as on submit.

Things I'm achieving here:

- Replacing spaces and commas as thousand-separators (`100 000.25 -> 100000.25` and `100,000.25 -> 100000.25`
- Replacing commas a decimal pointer with a dot (`100000,25 -> 100000.25`)

How would you improve the code and are there some edge cases I'm forgetting?

```
function sanitizeValue(value) {
    return value.replace(/ /g, '')
                .replace(/\./g, ',')                        
                .replace(/[,](?=.*[,])/g, "")
                .replace(/,/g, '.')
}

var form = document.getElementById('form')
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    Object.values(inputs).forEach(function(input) {
        input.value = sanitizeValue(input.value)
    })
}

Object.values(inputs).forEach(input => {
    input.onpaste = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault()
        let pasteValue = ev.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        ev.target.value = sanitizeValue(pasteValue)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## Don't guess!

You should not attempt to correct client input unless you make sure that the client knows (via a click) that a change has been made.

Converting a value like `100,1.0` to `1001.0` is a guess. The client may have intended only the `100`, or the `1.0` and your guess may not be noticed.

You can vet input as it is entered or on paste, removing non numeric characters (which you don't do) eg `"a100a"` will become `100`, but when there is ambiguity like `"a100a00"` it should be considered not a number.

If the result is not a number use standard validation warnings rather than guessing.